# Will developers be able to use ruby or python for apps on ubuntu mobile?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Will we be able to use python, ruby or other languages to develop apps for Ubuntu tablets and phones?

Comment: Voting this down because it clearly says at the SDK download that you can program in C, too. And when there a C binding exist, any language will do. Please show some effort and read before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Python and Ubuntu are a couple made in heaven, they'll always be together!

Jokes apart, you'll always be able to use python or ruby for developing apps for Ubuntu on phones. Apart from these two, I am not sure whether other programming languages are supported.

You may want to look at this question too:

[Can I develop apps in python for Ubuntu on phones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235369/can-i-develop-ubuntu-for-phones-apps-in-python)

Comment: Pretty sure any language with Qt/QML bindings would be supported, it simply being GNU/Linux and all.